# Nginx, Basic_Auth for directory listing only (not files, sub folders)

Tags: nginx, basic-authentication

anyone know of a way for NGINX to apply basic authentication to the directory listing (root directory in my case) but not to the invidiual files and subfolders within that root folder?

For example: if I accessed http://example.com I would be presented with basic authentication

but if I accessed http://example.com/audio.mp3 I would be able to access it without basic authentication on (publicly available)

Here is a sample of my nginx block

```
 server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    # Configure SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/ssl.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/ssl.key;
    include /etc/nginx/includes/ssl.conf;
    location ~ /$ {

        auth_basic "Admin Access";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/ssl/certs/nginx/.htpasswd;
        include /etc/nginx/includes/proxy.conf;
        proxy_pass http://111.111.111.111;
        autoindex on;

    }
    location / {
    try_files $uri =404;
    }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Using `proxy_pass` and `autoindex` in the same location does not make sense. What is the purpose of `http://111.111.111.111`?

Comment: that's fair, `autoindex` is unnecessary here--the proxy backend is there because I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy (for docker containers)